# Margin-top seems to be going haywire

Tags: html, css

I have a div, which contains an image and description. When I change margin-top of `.describing`, the container div moves:

[image][image][image]

HTML:

```
<div class="project">
    <a href="img/projects/a/a6.png" data-lightbox="a" data-title="A* algorithm realization">
        <img class="projim" src="img/projects/a/acover.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/projects/a/a6.png'"  onmouseout="this.src='img/projects/a/acover.png'"/>
    </a>
    <a class="hidden" href="img/projects/a/a1.png" data-lightbox="a" data-title="A* algorithm realization">
    </a>
    <a class="hidden" href="img/projects/a/a2.png" data-lightbox="a" data-title="A* algorithm realization">
    </a>            
    <a class="hidden" href="img/projects/a/a3.png" data-lightbox="a" data-title="A* algorithm realization">
    </a>
    <a class="hidden" href="img/projects/a/a4.png" data-lightbox="a" data-title="A* algorithm realization">
    </a>
    <a class="hidden" href="img/projects/a/a5.png" data-lightbox="a" data-title="A* algorithm realization">
    </a>
    <p class="describing">
        My realization of A* pathfinding algorithm.
    </p>
</div>

<div class="project">
    <a href="img/projects/fl/fl1.png" data-lightbox="fl" data-title="Follow the light">
        <img class="projimfl" src="img/projects/fl/flcover.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='img/projects/fl/fl1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/projects/fl/flcover.jpg'"/>
    </a>
    <a class="hidden" href="img/projects/fl/fl2.png" data-lightbox="fl" data-title="Follow the light">
    </a>
    <a class="hidden" href="img/projects/fl/fl3.png" data-lightbox="fl" data-title="Follow the light">
    </a>
    <p class="describingfl">
        Very hard game with cute graphics.
        Called "Follow the light".
    </p>
</div>
```

css:

```
body{
    background-size: overlay;
    background: rgb(72, 158, 136);
}


.project{
    margin:2% 1% 1% 3%; 
    padding-top: 1em;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 12em;
    height: 19em;
    display: inline-block;

    box-shadow: 0 0 1em #272727;
}

.projim{
    display: table;
    width: 8em;
    height: 13em;
    margin: auto;

}

.describing{
    color:#6a6a6a; 
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;

    border-top: 1px dashed #a39e9e; 
    margin-top:  1em;
    padding-top: 1em;
}

.projimfl{
    display: table;
    width: 8em;
    height: 7em;
    margin: auto;

}

.describingfl{
    color:#6a6a6a; 
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;

    border-top: 1px dashed #a39e9e; 
    margin-top:  6em;
    padding-top: 1em;
}

.hidden{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: That's strange. Giving a negative top-margin will make it apply a positive top-margin. O.O Maybe margin-collapse-something-something?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this in a sandbox environment, like http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: @ajp http://jsfiddle.net/am9rC/

Comment: 1st thing i want to know is why the are connected ? 
I change `margin-top` for `p` of the second element and my 1st element changes its position. WHY ???

Comment: @bjb568. laughting so loud that it hard to image

Comment: Well, I think that is because of margin-collapse - when a parent has no border/padding on side-X, margin-X of a child flush against side-X will cause the parent to use the margin-X, instead of a child.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is quite simple, daling with `inline-block` elements (your `.project`) is preferable to set

```
vertical-align: top ;
```

or any other property value https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align
in order to prevent mis-alignments due to content flow.

*[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wejaw/1/edit)*

Comment: Dam you inline-blocks. Actually, I love you but whatever.

Comment: Thank you , guys. Now i can go sleep!